# jasmine test access a promise inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm having an issue accessing the return value of a promise when calling a controller function. The function is called and then service method is invoked, but the return data is undefined. Do I need to mock the return value or can I return the actual value as it's running a stubby that returns a JSON object.

I have the following controller method (simplified for brevity)

```
   function init() {
            myService.myServiceMethod()
                .then(function(data) {
                    vm.myvalue = data[0].results;
                });
        }

        vm.init();
```

and my test

```
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/myendpoint').respond(data);


        $httpBackend.expectGET('/myendpoint').respond(data);


        myService.myServiceMethod().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        });

        // $httpBackend.flush(); // Flush the backend. Important!
        scope.$digest(); 

        expect(data).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: Have you looked at Jasmine `done()` functions?

Answer (score 0):

Timing problem:

```
myService.myServiceMethod().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    // data is filled here, if myServiceMethod() has some response
});

// data is undefined!!! 
// Why? The service call is asynchron, so you have to put the expect inside it
expect(data).toBeDefined();
```

-

```
myService.myServiceMethod().then(function (data) {
    expect(data).toBeDefined();
    });
```

Comment: I did try that originally. If I mock the data object and then return the promise, data still returns undefined.

Comment: If you do it like above, it should work. Even if you mock the data object (in the service call), it's still a timing issue, because its asynchron.